# How to remove a ? from a url with htaccess using 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I need an htaccess 301 redirect for dynamic urls going from this url:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/?content/page1
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/content/page1
```

My current htaccess rule is:

```
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !="" 
RewriteRule ^index.php(/.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301]
```

the problem is I get urls like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?content/page1
```

How can I remove that question mark (?) from the url. Also this is for about 20 different urls in this pattern. I would like the rule to work for all my urls needing to be 301 in this pattern.

Comment: use code blocks, please.

Answer (score 0):

End the target in a `?`.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php(/.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1? [R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for reply Ignacio. That one makes my original url redirect to homepage instead of the new url. To answer your question, I don't want any ? in the url. We are using Codeigniter framework if that is any help.